# Android Studio Updating failed while updating from 1.5.1 to 2.0

Tags: android

The 75mb patch file is downloading but  it is showing some java compilation errors file not found,and installation failed

Comment: Can you attach please more details? Maybe a screenshot or exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps that I have done to upgrade my android studio

You can download android studio 2.0 from below official link

[Click Here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.0.0.20/android-studio-ide-143.2739321-windows.zip) to download Android studio

After download complete extract file and copy that "android studio" folder to your existing android studio installed folder

Probably C://ProgramFiles/Android and so on..

I prefer to make a copy of already installed folder and then delete it from existing path and than move the downloaded folder here.

As I came to an issue of multiple settings available of android studio so advice you to make a backup and delete existing one and than copy new folder to that path.

Your android studio will be updated

This works for me... Hope will work for you as well.. Thanks